# Extremely high memory usage for mad.exe on Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, memory, virtual-memory

Hello I am running a Server 2003 server. I keep getting error messages saying to "increase page file size" When I looked in task manager for culprits I got `mad.exe` is using over 1G of virtual memory and over 100M of physical memory.

What could be causing such extreme usages of memory. Also, I've heard there was Norton problems with `mad.exe`, but we do not have Norton installed on the server.

Also, this server is *very* low usage. It is only used as a SVN and development database server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that's an Exchange server, then mad.exe is a perfectly legitimate process; it shouldn't be using that much memory, sure, but at least it really should be there.

If that's not an Exchange server, then you definitely have something to worry about...

Comment: It's an old server. I know it's not currently functioning as one, but maybe it was setup with Exchange before I came on. I'll check.

Comment: Ok, exchange is setup, but the service is disabled.

Comment: mad.exe is the executable for the Exchange System Attendant service; is it disabled?

Comment: Actually POP3 and IMAP is disabled for serving, so I'm not sure why that service is even running.. I stopped it now no more high memory usage

Comment: I'm anyway quite surprised, mad.exe usually doesn't take up that much memory; that would be normal for the Exchange database engine ("store.exe"), not for the System Attendant.

Comment: If Exchange isn't used anymore, it would anyway be a lot better to uninstall it from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Mad.exe is the Exchange System Attendant. Is that service stopped?